# Okay to call Marshal.CoTaskMem(ptrA) after using Marshal.StringToHGlobakAnsi?

Tags: c#, free, intptr

Here's my code:

```
IntPtr myPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("".PadLeft(myLength, ' '));
MyCFunc(myPtr);
string myStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(myPtr);
if (myPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(myStr);
```

My Questions are

1. Did I have to call only Marshal.FreeHGlobal instead of Marshal.FreeCoTakMem?  (line 5)
2. Is it perfect to use StringToHGlobalAnsi(SRRING.PadLeft)? (line 1)

For more information, my code is working mostly in my work. But sometimes 'myStr'(line 3) has unexpected value (probably broken memory). So I will try to change the free method. I just wondered and want to make sure my choices is the best. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All allocations functions have their own "dual". It is inappropriate to use `FreeCoTaskMem` if memory has not been allocated with `AllocCoTaskMem`, and `StringToHGlobalAnsi` [explicitly documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi#remarks) that you should use `FreeHGlobal`. So no, this code is not OK. This is in fact an overcomplicated way of doing things -- if you need to marshal a writable (out) buffer, use `StringBuilder` or use unsafe code and pin a `char[]`.

Comment: C code is rife with off-by-one bugs, caused by strings being terminated with a trailing 0.  So consider myLength + 1.  That does not necessarily avoids memory corruption, MyCFunc() is a very dangerous function when you can't pass the maximum string length.  Just add the check: if (myStr.Length > myLength) throw new Exception("Memory corruption detected");

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answers are so much helpful.